# Tinymce blur function not working when there are multiple editable textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, onblur

Tinymce blur function not working properly . I have multiple elements where i am using tinymce editor . I am using dblclick event to edit a textarea every thing is working fine but blur event is not triggering when i click on the other textarea element and but blur event is triggering when i click out side of the element mean page area(body)

This is what i have done so far :

```
  function my_function(element_id)
  {


          tinymce.init({
          selector: '#editable_' + element_id,
          inline: true,
          fixed_toolbar_container: "#element_"+element_id,
          plugins: [
              "advlist autolink lists link charmap   anchor",
              "  code fullscreen",
              "insertdatetime  table  paste textcolor"
          ],
          menubar: false,
          toolbar1: " undo redo | styleselect | fontselect  |  hr | removeformat",
          toolbar2: " forecolor backcolor |  bold italic underline | fontsizeselect",
          toolbar3: "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link | charmap ",
          fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 40pt 44pt 48pt',

          setup : function(editor)
          {



              editor.on('blur', function(e){

                  // do some stuff
                  alert(1)
              })

          } 
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.on("init",function(ed, evt) {

        var dom = ed.dom;
        var doc = ed.getWin();

        tinymce.dom.Event.add(doc, 'blur', function(e) {
            // Do something when the editor window is blured.
            alert('blur!!!');
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: dear i am using tinymce4

Comment: please try getDoc() instead of getWin(). Hope it will work

Comment: still undefined . Check my plugins above and tell me that there is any plugin missing?

Comment: TypeError: ed.getWin is not a function. (In 'ed.getWin()', 'ed.getWin' is undefined)